# Replace Value in DataFrame with Regex function return Value

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

**Goal:**

In a dataframe containing concatenated Proper Names, split each name at capitalization of name with a space, and replace that value in corresponding dataframe element. Testing on `regex` function yields correct result when tested on independent values.

**Process**

```
data = {'Full_Name' : ["JackSmithDanielsSmith", "JoeShmoeDoeBoe", "MikeJohnChaoCow"]
        'First_Name': ["JackSmith", "JoeShmoeDoe", "Mike"]
        'Last_Name' : ["DanielsSmith", "Boe", "JohnChaoCow"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Regex Function (returns expected results)

def CapitalizeWord(word):
    word = str(word)
    return re.sub("([A-Z])", " \\1", word).strip()

# Procedure
for column in df:
    replace_data = []
    columnObj = df[column]
    for word in columnObj:
        word_split = CapitalizeWord(word)
        replace_data.append(word_split)
    df.replace(columnObj, append_data)
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-b8089f04c8c8> in <module>
----> 9     df.replace(columnObj, replace_data)


~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method)
   4261             limit=limit,
   4262             regex=regex,
-> 4263             method=method,
   4264         )
   4265 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method)
   6719                         )
   6720                 else:
-> 6721                     raise TypeError("value argument must be scalar, dict, or " "Series")
   6722 
   6723             elif is_list_like(to_replace):  # [NA, ''] -> [0, 'missing']

TypeError: value argument must be scalar, dict, or Series
```

**Research:**

In the `df.replace` [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) , I noticed my issue is similar to what is referenced in the ending paragraphs. I'm not fully understanding the definition, when used with `regex`.

Comment: could you add a dataframe showing ur expected output

Comment: Reflected in chosen answer @sammywemmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('([A-Z])', " \\1"))
```

Output:

```
                   Full_Name      First_Name       Last_Name
0   Jack Smith Daniels Smith      Jack Smith   Daniels Smith
1          Joe Shmoe Doe Boe   Joe Shmoe Doe             Boe
2         Mike John Chao Cow            Mike   John Chao Cow
```

Comment: This was very insightful, cut out many steps, and greatly improved processing speed!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best, but I would `stack` and `unstack`:

```
(df.stack()
   .str.extractall('([A-Z][a-z]*)')
   .groupby(level=[0,1])
   .agg(' '.join)[0]
   .unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
      First_Name                 Full_Name      Last_Name
0     Jack Smith  Jack Smith Daniels Smith  Daniels Smith
1  Joe Shmoe Doe         Joe Shmoe Doe Boe            Boe
2           Mike        Mike John Chao Cow  John Chao Cow
```